# Excel formula changes when columns are added dynamically

Tags: excel, ssis, excel-interop

I have a excel workbook where Sheet1 Cell A10 refers to the Sheet2 Cell A1.
I am using the formula

```
Sheet2!$A$1
```

I run an SSIS package, which has a script task that adds a column and a row to the Sheet2.
Now the formula automaticlly changes to

```
Sheet2!$B$2
```

Although I am using absolute formula, I dont get what I expected. Any ideas on how to achieve what I want?

Comment: I want to avoid doing it in the script task. The formula used is in a rectangle instead of a normal cell.

Answer (score 1):

Please try say `=INDIRECT(A11)` (adjust A11 to suit) instead of `=Sheet2!$A$1` and in A11 (or wherever chosen) `=ADDRESS(1,1,1,1,"Sheet2")`. I think this should be what you want if I understand you correctly - ie you do not want to follow A1 around as rows/columns are added but literally the top left hand corner, regardless of column/row changes.